# Can I make a conditional design based on other cells (Excel)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make this by Excel rules:
[image: Spreadsheet example]

That any cell (in column B) that is near (*beside*) "1" (in A) will be red, and any cell near (*beside*) "2" will be green.
Is there a possible way to do it (without VBA, only with excel rules)?

Comment: What is "near"? Do you mean equal?

Comment: Yes what do mean `near` here? If you meant to say only its equal to `1` or `2` then select the range `B`, Goto CF (`ALT`+`H`+`L`+`N` <-- Shortcut to open), Select the last rule and enter the formula as `=A1=1` click format to choose preference and select `OK` twice done. Same way for `2`. If not then explain more. Also numbers shouldn't be within speechmarks/quotes.

Comment: I hope now it's more clear :) @ReddyLutonadio

Comment: Yes, and it works! :) Thank you! @MayukhBhattacharya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Conditional Formatting` using the last rule --> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

[image]

---

- Select the `Column B` range from `B1:B8`
- GoTo `Home` Tab --> From `Styles` Group --> Click on `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` (Alternatively, shortcut to open the `New Formatting Rule` window box is --> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> )
- Select the last rule --> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- In the `edit the rule description` enter the following formula:

---

`=A1=1`

---

- Click `Format` --> Choose your preferences.
- Click `OK` -> Twice. Done.

---

Same way for `2` repeat the process but change `A1=2` and change the formatting. Or you can select the range `B1:B8` press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` --> Click `Duplicate` --> Click on `Edit` --> Change in the rule description `1` to `2` and change the formatting press `OK` done.

---